# Two circles defining a line

Tags: geometry, circles

We have two dots $d_1,d_2$ moving on circles $C_1, C_2$ with radii $r_1, r_2$. The circles are moving at speed of $s_1, s_2$. A line is drawn between $d_1$ and $d_2$. When does this line have some segment inside the smaller of the two circles?

[image: 2circles1]
[image: 2circles2]

There is some code [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/two-circles-and-a-line/4540337881219072).

Comment: Have you tried more specific cases? Maybe tried simulating it to get a feel for the problem?

Comment: @George; i did, see new link added to Q

Comment: Perhaps you'd find it useful to consider the problem in a frame of reference rotating at the same speed as one of the dots, i.e., in which one of the dots is fixed.

Comment: Maybe consider measuring the angle between the radius of the small circle and the line $d_1d_2$ and comparing that with the angle interval necessary to be tangent or outside the small circle?

Comment: Are they both moving at the same sense? (i.e both clockwise)

Comment: You need only to consider relative angular velocity $ \omega $ of say outer circle with respect to inner one so the difference vector lies  in ring area  outside of inner circle's tangent.

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello; i don't know that it makes much difference, but for the answer (at least 25 points!) in the same direction

Comment: @Jon: Did you read Narasimham's comment? It depends on the relative angular velocity, so it does make a difference whether they're going in the same or opposite sense, since the angular velocities are added in one case and subtracted in the other.

Comment: @joriki; yes but the difference in the maths is not significant. although i have fixed this oversight in my code. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the suffix 1 refers to the inner circle, and $s_1$ is the angular speed of the inner circle, then relative to the point on the outer circle, the point on the inner circle completes one revolution in time $\tau=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$, where $\omega=|s_1-s_2|$. The fraction of this time when the joining chord does not intersect the inner circle is given by $T=\frac{\theta}{\pi}\tau$, where $\theta=\arccos(\frac{r_1}{r_2})$, from which you can obtain an expression for the time when the chord intersects the inner circle, i.e. $\tau-T$